# Amber test bench not compiling

Tags: bash, xilinx

I am getting this error while running a script. I got all dependencies according to the readme doc.

```
Test hello-world, type 4
make -s -C ../mini-libc MIN_SIZE=1
make[1]: amber-crosstool-not-defined-gcc: Command not found
make[1]: *** [printf.o] Error 127
make: *** [mini-libc] Error 2
Error compiling boot-loader-serial
```

Comment: Please read https://askubuntu.com/help/how-to-ask which will help you with asking questions here.

Comment: "amber-crosstool-not-defined-gcc" seems self-explanatory. Do you have gcc installed?